# Automating creation of title block in Sharepoint 2010 Wiki pages

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-wiki

Standards on my enterprise Wiki include a page title similar to Wikipedia's - a Colored Heading 1 copy of the page's title, followed by a horizontal rule, at the top of the page.

However, people have to manually enter this. Is there a way I can modify a template somewhere to automatically add Colored Heading 1 (exact title of page) followed by a horizontal rule to new pages? This would make my wiki a lot more user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Modify the WIKI page layout and if it's not dynamic, just use plain ole HTML at the top of the page layout. Then any pages you create from it will inherit that heading.

```
<h1 class='wikiHead'>MY COLORFUL TITLE</h1>
<hr/>
```